# C++: Assigning the result of bitwise AND to a bool

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-and

I have the following loop in C++, compiled with g++ 4.1.2:

```
while(1) {
    int status = getStatus();
    bool firstOk = status & 0x1;
    bool secondOk = status & 0x2;
    if(firstOk != m_firstOk) {
        logStatus(1, firstOk);
        m_firstOk = firstOk;
    }
    if(secondOk != m_secondOk) {
        logStatus(2, secondOk);
        m_secondOk = secondOk;
    }

    sleep(1);
}
```

Note logStatus() receives its parameters by value, so the parameter is not modified. m_firstOk and m_secondOk are of course bool member attributes.

This was working fine until now. I received a report that it didn't detect when firstOk changed. I attached to the running process with gdb. It was in the sleep() line and I got astonished when I saw the following:

```
(gdb) p m_firstOk
$1 = true
(gdb) p m_secondOk
$2 = true
(gdb) p firstOk
$3 = 244
```

WTF? How can firstOk be 244 when it should be the result of a bitwise AND with 0x1? I know a boolean is in fact stored as an integer, but how could my bitwise AND be ignored? Since it's 244, it's being evaluated as true when it should be false, which is the cause of the problem.

Isn't assigning the result of a bitwise AND to a boolean safe? Is this a gcc bug? Or should I do something like the following?

```
bool firstOk = (status & 0x1) ? true : false;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't `status` be unsigned?

Comment: Are you sure that `firstOk` exists during the `sleep()` call? As it is a simple bool and it is not used any longer it may have been reused for something else. What does `logStatus()` say?

Comment: Did you compile without any optimization? You could try to print the value of `firstOk` to make sure that what Csq said is no longer the case.

Comment: Look at the disassembly.

Comment: Pubby: it shouldn't matter. The value of status can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. Nothing else.

Comment: Csq: seems like you're right. If I add a breakpoint just before the sleep(), the value of firstOk is false, not 244. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The local variables `firstOk` and `secondOk` are not "live" when you reach the `sleep()` call, so even if they *had* been allocated stack slots, it's entirely possible (and indeed quite likely) that their values aren't stored anywhere any longer.

If you need to debug either of these variables, you need to either

1. Re-declare them as `static`, which will allocate them persistent storage off the stack
2. Move the declaration of `firstOk` and `secondOk` to an outer scope.  (Note, this may not be enough, unless you move them out to file scope.)
3. Copy the values of `firstOk` and `secondOk` to persistent variables or variables live in an outer scope, and inspect those.

In any case, I would revert any of the above debug measures once you complete your debugging process.  :-)

As for your final question, the statement `bool firstOk = status & 0x1` is perfectly fine, as is the statement that follows it setting `secondOk`.  Assigning an `int` to a `bool` coerces zero/non-zero values to `false` and `true`.

As to your actual bug (somehow you missed a transition on `firstOk`), I don't see where you might have lost it in this code.  This part of the code seems fine.  Is it possible that your `getStatus()` function needs to be called more often than once a second?  Can anything else write to `m_firstOk` or `m_secondOk`?  Their declarations aren't shown, so presumably these exist in an outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that is possible is if:

1) the stack has been overwritten somehow.

2) The value of the temporary is not that significant once you get to the sleep line, so the compiler is not tracking it anymore so that memory slot might have been used for something else!

If it works at first and then later on starts behaving wrong then it is most likely not a compiler bug for that section of code.

Comment: No, this is wrong. The conversion integral => `bool` is well-defined, and the respective type sizes are irrelevant. No truncation happens. And furthermore the same is true in an assignment to `bool` and in an `if` statement so this is doubly wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The correct assignment should be:

```
bool firstOk = (status & 0x1) == 0x01;
```

Or in general:

```
bool flag = (value & mask) == mask;
```

Comment: Well, 1. this does something different (test if the whole mask is present vs. test if some bits of a mask are set), and 2. the problem seems to be sth different, namely that `& 0x1` in OP's code seems to evaluate to something having more bits set.

Comment: I agree that this is a superior way of working with flags, and that C++ shouldn’t allow implicit integral => `bool` conversions. But it does, and the code is well-defined.